# Python Scrapy not parsing all items

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to build a simple scrapy crawler for the e-commerce site.

It follows links and seems to find all needed elements by XPath. However, for some reason, it is only parsing 1200 items instead of 1531, like there is some kind of limitation to it. 
I've tried switching selectors and even simulating clicks on next page in selenium with no success.

Here is full crawler code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    category=scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()


class ObiSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "obi_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.obi.ru/vsyo-dlya-doma/lakokrasochnye-materialy/c/296"]


    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='first-level dashed']/li/a/@href").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_page)   


    def parse_page(self, response):
        ans=response.xpath("//li[@class='product large']")
        for prod in ans:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=Product(), selector=prod)
            loader.add_xpath('category', "//div[@class='head dashed selectable']/a/text()")
            loader.add_xpath('name', ".//span[@class='description']/p/text()")
            loader.add_xpath('price', ".//span[@class='price']/span/@data-csscontent")
            yield loader.load_item()
        path = response.xpath("//div[@id='PaginationLinks']/a/@href").extract()
        for link in path:
            if "?page" in link:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_page)



process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(ObiSpider)
process.start()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details: does the scrapy log show any errors or non-200 response codes? If yes post the log here. Also please check if the scraper actually visited all pages it should visit. The even limit of 1200 sounds like it got blocked at some point (after accessing 20 pages with 60 products each) and wasn't able to access all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not problem in your spider - but in calculate of product count.
You can see in page with list of products:
[image]

Some products has some combination, but 1 link in list.
Etc:
[image]